# Which method is OLA & Uber using to get car location while in driving?

Tags: ios, location, mapkit

I have used the Map control in my iOS application. I have to get the user's car location while the user in driving (Run time update like Ola and Uber Apps).

**1). Which method are they using to get the user location while moving (API call, Web socket or any other else)?**

**2). If are they using API call, How many once (Time interval) will they call API to update the UI?**

Share you valuable suggestions. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: your question is too broad to answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do with firebase database . Firebase have realtime database . So when some data is update in firebase in particular node in firebase database , so get realtime data syncing in your app .. just you have to make proper database structure  and observing proper node from database is require.

Answer (score 0):

> Both Ola and Uber use enterprise Google Maps API, in fact most of the
>   Geo-location based apps use Google maps API.
>
> Google maps API are available at Google's developer forum. You can
>   make use of that API for your app and you can get your current cards
>   which can then be used to show on maps.
>
> Here's the link to add this API in your site/app:
>
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/
>
> Also, you can add multiple features like navigation, street view and
>   satellite imagery with the help of this:
>
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/
>
> This is used in the most famous game:- Pokemon go.
>
> It's free to a certain limit if you want to try for your own Apps,
>   after the free limit you need to pay for it.

Comment: @Raja, Are you sure is that Uber and OLA using Enterprise version for smooth navigation of car icon while travelling.

Comment: I think so. But there is not mandatory to use enterprise version for moving animation. Eventually, we have done the execution using web socket now.